# How is input data in forms saved before submitting?

Tags: html, forms, temporary

I have a question about input data in html forms.

How and where is data, that a user writes into an html form, saved before he submits it? Especially if it is a form with multiple tabs, where the user can switch between the different tabs and the input data is still there after switching from one to another tab.
Is there a temporary storage in the browser?

I don't mean data, which is explicitly saved in cookies or local storage. I refer to data, which has just been written into an input field by the user (and waits for being submitted).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look something about `browser cookie`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

If you are developing an app, for example using React, the data will be stored in the component state until you submit. Where is this state stored? It depends, but normally on RAM.

It is more complex than it sounds. Normally there is a play between the CPU, RAM and Disk, because getting data from RAM is faster than from Disk, and the user device will normally have multiple active processes.

Also, on the web, you can use the browser cookies to persist the data (but this is not the answer of your question, the answer is RAM).

### RAM vs Disk

RAM has a very fast path to the computer's CPU, or central processing unit, the brain of the computer that does most of the work. RAM is random access as opposed to sequential access. Data that's accessed sequentially includes stuff that's written to your hard disk drive, for example.